# How to Draw a Roman Column in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, draw, mathcha

I would like to be a able to draw (using LaTeX tools) a  reasonable approximation to the following image of a Roman column:

[image]

I had produced the above using Inkscape (drawing first a bitmap of an imported image and then colorizing it a bit). Later, I made some adjustments to its original proportions.

Any help you may provide in drawing something like this in LaTeX is appreciated, even if it is somewhat less detailed than the above.

Thank you.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Hi, kindest. The Mathcha is a tool to draw in TikZ. I think that the tag it is specific to use a external tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have drawn using [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) (tool) for your Roman column(s) in `LaTeX`....They are the only unique pieces that I have left in my museum .

You can choose the colors directly into the code. I remember when I was drawing at my school when I was a student, I used a sanguine pencil.
They are not perfect Roman columns like your drawing...but they are very similar....
Here there is the code and the screenshot.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,412); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 412

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp05311833326654858] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (98,303) -- (222,303) -- (222,293.03) -- (98,293.03) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp3517834555646895] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (102,287.93) .. controls (102,287.18) and (102.61,286.57) .. (103.37,286.57) -- (215.63,286.57) .. controls (216.39,286.57) and (217,287.18) .. (217,287.93) -- (217,292.03) .. controls (217,292.78) and (216.39,293.39) .. (215.63,293.39) -- (103.37,293.39) .. controls (102.61,293.39) and (102,292.78) .. (102,292.03) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp9185263749699308] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (105.04,270.59) .. controls (105.81,276.29) and (105.18,281.82) .. (103.37,286.57) -- (80.46,271.48) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (105.04,270.59) .. controls (105.81,276.29) and (105.18,281.82) .. (103.37,286.57) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp5680869238396258] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (215.63,286.57) .. controls (214.13,281.01) and (214.03,275.45) .. (215.21,270.51) -- (239.89,282.47) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (215.63,286.57) .. controls (214.13,281.01) and (214.03,275.45) .. (215.21,270.51) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5673847912266565] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (105.04,270.59) -- (215.21,270.51) ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp6708182766486024] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (112.62,265.86) .. controls (112.62,265.23) and (113.13,264.73) .. (113.75,264.73) -- (206.5,264.73) .. controls (207.12,264.73) and (207.62,265.23) .. (207.62,265.86) -- (207.62,269.24) .. controls (207.62,269.86) and (207.12,270.37) .. (206.5,270.37) -- (113.75,270.37) .. controls (113.13,270.37) and (112.62,269.86) .. (112.62,269.24) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp3273648015265267] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (222.83,46.42) -- (98.83,46.42) -- (98.83,56.39) -- (222.83,56.39) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp26194342519058034] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (218.83,61.48) .. controls (218.83,62.24) and (218.22,62.85) .. (217.47,62.85) -- (105.2,62.85) .. controls (104.44,62.85) and (103.83,62.24) .. (103.83,61.48) -- (103.83,57.39) .. controls (103.83,56.63) and (104.44,56.02) .. (105.2,56.02) -- (217.47,56.02) .. controls (218.22,56.02) and (218.83,56.63) .. (218.83,57.39) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp09209144456658369] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (215.79,78.83) .. controls (215.02,73.12) and (215.66,67.6) .. (217.47,62.85) -- (240.38,77.94) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (215.79,78.83) .. controls (215.02,73.12) and (215.66,67.6) .. (217.47,62.85) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp4664296079321517] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (105.2,62.85) .. controls (106.71,68.4) and (106.8,73.96) .. (105.63,78.91) -- (80.94,66.95) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (105.2,62.85) .. controls (106.71,68.4) and (106.8,73.96) .. (105.63,78.91) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5454640292284123] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (215.79,78.83) -- (105.63,78.91) ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp08222912707583419] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (208.21,83.56) .. controls (208.21,84.18) and (207.7,84.69) .. (207.08,84.69) -- (114.34,84.69) .. controls (113.71,84.69) and (113.21,84.18) .. (113.21,83.56) -- (113.21,80.17) .. controls (113.21,79.55) and (113.71,79.05) .. (114.34,79.05) -- (207.08,79.05) .. controls (207.7,79.05) and (208.21,79.55) .. (208.21,80.17) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp02981342829226663] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (207,86) -- (207,264.73) -- (113.75,264.73) -- (113.75,86) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp6052819688472759] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (119.7,86.41) .. controls (120.42,86.41) and (121,86.99) .. (121,87.71) -- (121,261.7) .. controls (121,262.42) and (120.42,263) .. (119.7,263) -- (118.3,263) .. controls (117.58,263) and (117,262.42) .. (117,261.7) -- (117,87.71) .. controls (117,86.99) and (117.58,86.41) .. (118.3,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp14935828771553683] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (202.7,86.41) .. controls (203.42,86.41) and (204,86.99) .. (204,87.71) -- (204,261.7) .. controls (204,262.42) and (203.42,263) .. (202.7,263) -- (201.3,263) .. controls (200.58,263) and (200,262.42) .. (200,261.7) -- (200,87.71) .. controls (200,86.99) and (200.58,86.41) .. (201.3,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp7826541468020711] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (132.07,86.41) .. controls (133.69,86.41) and (135,87.72) .. (135,89.34) -- (135,260.07) .. controls (135,261.69) and (133.69,263) .. (132.07,263) -- (128.92,263) .. controls (127.31,263) and (126,261.69) .. (126,260.07) -- (126,89.34) .. controls (126,87.72) and (127.31,86.41) .. (128.92,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp06535794308021847] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (192.08,86.41) .. controls (193.69,86.41) and (195,87.72) .. (195,89.34) -- (195,260.07) .. controls (195,261.69) and (193.69,263) .. (192.08,263) -- (188.93,263) .. controls (187.31,263) and (186,261.69) .. (186,260.07) -- (186,89.34) .. controls (186,87.72) and (187.31,86.41) .. (188.93,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp4692211026110651] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (151.8,86.69) .. controls (154.67,86.69) and (157,89.01) .. (157,91.89) -- (157,258.07) .. controls (157,260.95) and (154.67,263.27) .. (151.8,263.27) -- (146.2,263.27) .. controls (143.33,263.27) and (141,260.95) .. (141,258.07) -- (141,91.89) .. controls (141,89.01) and (143.33,86.69) .. (146.2,86.69) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp13537095335481952] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (173.8,86.69) .. controls (176.67,86.69) and (179,89.01) .. (179,91.89) -- (179,258.07) .. controls (179,260.95) and (176.67,263.27) .. (173.8,263.27) -- (168.2,263.27) .. controls (165.33,263.27) and (163,260.95) .. (163,258.07) -- (163,91.89) .. controls (163,89.01) and (165.33,86.69) .. (168.2,86.69) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp513940339428326] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (347,303) -- (471,303) -- (471,293.03) -- (347,293.03) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp26534635864417777] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (351,287.93) .. controls (351,287.18) and (351.61,286.57) .. (352.37,286.57) -- (464.63,286.57) .. controls (465.39,286.57) and (466,287.18) .. (466,287.93) -- (466,292.03) .. controls (466,292.78) and (465.39,293.39) .. (464.63,293.39) -- (352.37,293.39) .. controls (351.61,293.39) and (351,292.78) .. (351,292.03) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp035981748854030826] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (354.04,270.59) .. controls (354.81,276.29) and (354.18,281.82) .. (352.37,286.57) -- (329.46,271.48) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (354.04,270.59) .. controls (354.81,276.29) and (354.18,281.82) .. (352.37,286.57) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp5149583560702116] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (464.63,286.57) .. controls (463.13,281.01) and (463.03,275.45) .. (464.21,270.51) -- (488.89,282.47) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (464.63,286.57) .. controls (463.13,281.01) and (463.03,275.45) .. (464.21,270.51) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5892045629226417] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (354.04,270.59) -- (464.21,270.51) ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp0979247149439364] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (361.62,265.86) .. controls (361.62,265.23) and (362.13,264.73) .. (362.75,264.73) -- (455.5,264.73) .. controls (456.12,264.73) and (456.62,265.23) .. (456.62,265.86) -- (456.62,269.24) .. controls (456.62,269.86) and (456.12,270.37) .. (455.5,270.37) -- (362.75,270.37) .. controls (362.13,270.37) and (361.62,269.86) .. (361.62,269.24) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp4300660946738333] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (471.83,46.42) -- (347.83,46.42) -- (347.83,56.39) -- (471.83,56.39) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp7035165741413447] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (467.83,61.48) .. controls (467.83,62.24) and (467.22,62.85) .. (466.47,62.85) -- (354.2,62.85) .. controls (353.44,62.85) and (352.83,62.24) .. (352.83,61.48) -- (352.83,57.39) .. controls (352.83,56.63) and (353.44,56.02) .. (354.2,56.02) -- (466.47,56.02) .. controls (467.22,56.02) and (467.83,56.63) .. (467.83,57.39) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp09195981060411595] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (464.79,78.83) .. controls (464.02,73.12) and (464.66,67.6) .. (466.47,62.85) -- (489.38,77.94) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (464.79,78.83) .. controls (464.02,73.12) and (464.66,67.6) .. (466.47,62.85) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp14667266892322206] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (354.2,62.85) .. controls (355.71,68.4) and (355.8,73.96) .. (354.63,78.91) -- (329.94,66.95) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (354.2,62.85) .. controls (355.71,68.4) and (355.8,73.96) .. (354.63,78.91) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da23461020646488961] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (464.79,78.83) -- (354.63,78.91) ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp18715479523656375] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (457.21,83.56) .. controls (457.21,84.18) and (456.7,84.69) .. (456.08,84.69) -- (363.34,84.69) .. controls (362.71,84.69) and (362.21,84.18) .. (362.21,83.56) -- (362.21,80.17) .. controls (362.21,79.55) and (362.71,79.05) .. (363.34,79.05) -- (456.08,79.05) .. controls (456.7,79.05) and (457.21,79.55) .. (457.21,80.17) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp8089269236440244] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (456,86) -- (456,264.73) -- (362.75,264.73) -- (362.75,86) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp6421298108150144] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (368.7,86.41) .. controls (369.42,86.41) and (370,86.99) .. (370,87.71) -- (370,261.7) .. controls (370,262.42) and (369.42,263) .. (368.7,263) -- (367.3,263) .. controls (366.58,263) and (366,262.42) .. (366,261.7) -- (366,87.71) .. controls (366,86.99) and (366.58,86.41) .. (367.3,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp052712011169137485] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (451.7,86.41) .. controls (452.42,86.41) and (453,86.99) .. (453,87.71) -- (453,261.7) .. controls (453,262.42) and (452.42,263) .. (451.7,263) -- (450.3,263) .. controls (449.58,263) and (449,262.42) .. (449,261.7) -- (449,87.71) .. controls (449,86.99) and (449.58,86.41) .. (450.3,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp95369796325723] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (381.08,86.41) .. controls (382.69,86.41) and (384,87.72) .. (384,89.34) -- (384,260.07) .. controls (384,261.69) and (382.69,263) .. (381.08,263) -- (377.92,263) .. controls (376.31,263) and (375,261.69) .. (375,260.07) -- (375,89.34) .. controls (375,87.72) and (376.31,86.41) .. (377.92,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp5824628380490837] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (441.08,86.41) .. controls (442.69,86.41) and (444,87.72) .. (444,89.34) -- (444,260.08) .. controls (444,261.69) and (442.69,263) .. (441.08,263) -- (437.92,263) .. controls (436.31,263) and (435,261.69) .. (435,260.08) -- (435,89.34) .. controls (435,87.72) and (436.31,86.41) .. (437.92,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp8095353460016774] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (396.1,86.69) .. controls (398.25,86.69) and (400,88.43) .. (400,90.59) -- (400,259.37) .. controls (400,261.53) and (398.25,263.27) .. (396.1,263.27) -- (391.9,263.27) .. controls (389.75,263.27) and (388,261.53) .. (388,259.37) -- (388,90.59) .. controls (388,88.43) and (389.75,86.69) .. (391.9,86.69) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp4551352479655788] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (427.1,86.69) .. controls (429.25,86.69) and (431,88.43) .. (431,90.59) -- (431,259.37) .. controls (431,261.53) and (429.25,263.27) .. (427.1,263.27) -- (422.9,263.27) .. controls (420.75,263.27) and (419,261.53) .. (419,259.37) -- (419,90.59) .. controls (419,88.43) and (420.75,86.69) .. (422.9,86.69) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp9136580612305947] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (411.12,86.96) .. controls (413.28,86.96) and (415.02,88.71) .. (415.02,90.86) -- (415.02,259.65) .. controls (415.02,261.8) and (413.28,263.55) .. (411.12,263.55) -- (406.92,263.55) .. controls (404.77,263.55) and (403.02,261.8) .. (403.02,259.65) -- (403.02,90.86) .. controls (403.02,88.71) and (404.77,86.96) .. (406.92,86.96) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just only one piece:

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,412); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 412

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp513940339428326] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (347,303) -- (471,303) -- (471,293.03) -- (347,293.03) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp26534635864417777] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (351,287.93) .. controls (351,287.18) and (351.61,286.57) .. (352.37,286.57) -- (464.63,286.57) .. controls (465.39,286.57) and (466,287.18) .. (466,287.93) -- (466,292.03) .. controls (466,292.78) and (465.39,293.39) .. (464.63,293.39) -- (352.37,293.39) .. controls (351.61,293.39) and (351,292.78) .. (351,292.03) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp035981748854030826] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (354.04,270.59) .. controls (354.81,276.29) and (354.18,281.82) .. (352.37,286.57) -- (329.46,271.48) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (354.04,270.59) .. controls (354.81,276.29) and (354.18,281.82) .. (352.37,286.57) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp5149583560702116] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (464.63,286.57) .. controls (463.13,281.01) and (463.03,275.45) .. (464.21,270.51) -- (488.89,282.47) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (464.63,286.57) .. controls (463.13,281.01) and (463.03,275.45) .. (464.21,270.51) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5892045629226417] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (354.04,270.59) -- (464.21,270.51) ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp0979247149439364] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (361.62,265.86) .. controls (361.62,265.23) and (362.13,264.73) .. (362.75,264.73) -- (455.5,264.73) .. controls (456.12,264.73) and (456.62,265.23) .. (456.62,265.86) -- (456.62,269.24) .. controls (456.62,269.86) and (456.12,270.37) .. (455.5,270.37) -- (362.75,270.37) .. controls (362.13,270.37) and (361.62,269.86) .. (361.62,269.24) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp4300660946738333] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (471.83,46.42) -- (347.83,46.42) -- (347.83,56.39) -- (471.83,56.39) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp7035165741413447] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (467.83,61.48) .. controls (467.83,62.24) and (467.22,62.85) .. (466.47,62.85) -- (354.2,62.85) .. controls (353.44,62.85) and (352.83,62.24) .. (352.83,61.48) -- (352.83,57.39) .. controls (352.83,56.63) and (353.44,56.02) .. (354.2,56.02) -- (466.47,56.02) .. controls (467.22,56.02) and (467.83,56.63) .. (467.83,57.39) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp09195981060411595] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (464.79,78.83) .. controls (464.02,73.12) and (464.66,67.6) .. (466.47,62.85) -- (489.38,77.94) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (464.79,78.83) .. controls (464.02,73.12) and (464.66,67.6) .. (466.47,62.85) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp14667266892322206] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (354.2,62.85) .. controls (355.71,68.4) and (355.8,73.96) .. (354.63,78.91) -- (329.94,66.95) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (354.2,62.85) .. controls (355.71,68.4) and (355.8,73.96) .. (354.63,78.91) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da23461020646488961] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (464.79,78.83) -- (354.63,78.91) ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp18715479523656375] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (457.21,83.56) .. controls (457.21,84.18) and (456.7,84.69) .. (456.08,84.69) -- (363.34,84.69) .. controls (362.71,84.69) and (362.21,84.18) .. (362.21,83.56) -- (362.21,80.17) .. controls (362.21,79.55) and (362.71,79.05) .. (363.34,79.05) -- (456.08,79.05) .. controls (456.7,79.05) and (457.21,79.55) .. (457.21,80.17) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp8089269236440244] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (456,86) -- (456,264.73) -- (362.75,264.73) -- (362.75,86) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp6421298108150144] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (368.7,86.41) .. controls (369.42,86.41) and (370,86.99) .. (370,87.71) -- (370,261.7) .. controls (370,262.42) and (369.42,263) .. (368.7,263) -- (367.3,263) .. controls (366.58,263) and (366,262.42) .. (366,261.7) -- (366,87.71) .. controls (366,86.99) and (366.58,86.41) .. (367.3,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp052712011169137485] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (451.7,86.41) .. controls (452.42,86.41) and (453,86.99) .. (453,87.71) -- (453,261.7) .. controls (453,262.42) and (452.42,263) .. (451.7,263) -- (450.3,263) .. controls (449.58,263) and (449,262.42) .. (449,261.7) -- (449,87.71) .. controls (449,86.99) and (449.58,86.41) .. (450.3,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp95369796325723] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (381.08,86.41) .. controls (382.69,86.41) and (384,87.72) .. (384,89.34) -- (384,260.07) .. controls (384,261.69) and (382.69,263) .. (381.08,263) -- (377.92,263) .. controls (376.31,263) and (375,261.69) .. (375,260.07) -- (375,89.34) .. controls (375,87.72) and (376.31,86.41) .. (377.92,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp5824628380490837] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (441.08,86.41) .. controls (442.69,86.41) and (444,87.72) .. (444,89.34) -- (444,260.08) .. controls (444,261.69) and (442.69,263) .. (441.08,263) -- (437.92,263) .. controls (436.31,263) and (435,261.69) .. (435,260.08) -- (435,89.34) .. controls (435,87.72) and (436.31,86.41) .. (437.92,86.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp8095353460016774] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (396.1,86.69) .. controls (398.25,86.69) and (400,88.43) .. (400,90.59) -- (400,259.37) .. controls (400,261.53) and (398.25,263.27) .. (396.1,263.27) -- (391.9,263.27) .. controls (389.75,263.27) and (388,261.53) .. (388,259.37) -- (388,90.59) .. controls (388,88.43) and (389.75,86.69) .. (391.9,86.69) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp4551352479655788] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (427.1,86.69) .. controls (429.25,86.69) and (431,88.43) .. (431,90.59) -- (431,259.37) .. controls (431,261.53) and (429.25,263.27) .. (427.1,263.27) -- (422.9,263.27) .. controls (420.75,263.27) and (419,261.53) .. (419,259.37) -- (419,90.59) .. controls (419,88.43) and (420.75,86.69) .. (422.9,86.69) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp9136580612305947] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 67; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (411.12,86.96) .. controls (413.28,86.96) and (415.02,88.71) .. (415.02,90.86) -- (415.02,259.65) .. controls (415.02,261.8) and (413.28,263.55) .. (411.12,263.55) -- (406.92,263.55) .. controls (404.77,263.55) and (403.02,261.8) .. (403.02,259.65) -- (403.02,90.86) .. controls (403.02,88.71) and (404.77,86.96) .. (406.92,86.96) -- cycle ;
  
\end{tikzpicture}
   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I have never used the tool. Looks good.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Do you like it? :)))) I assure you that Mathcha's tools are very limited...and I thought about it a bit before to create the Roman columns...hahahahah.

Comment: I think it's a good alternative if the drawing is not very systematic and/or you only need one version (and not 100 similar but different versions).

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for your assistance and for this remarkable drawing.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Hi, I am agree with you...I have only changed the pattern of the internal of the column to have a different rounded rectangle.

Comment: @mlchristians I'm glady to help you. :-).....I like the drawing.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to do it, directly with tikz:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{DB4323}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mycolor,line join=round]
  \def\r {2}   % radius
  \def\hs{4}   % height (shaft)
  \def\hc{0.5} % height (base, capital)
  % BASE, CAPITAL
  \foreach\i in {0,180}
  {%
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\i,shift={(0,-0.5*\hs-\hc)}]
      \draw (-0.5*\r,0) rectangle (0.5*\r,0.2*\hc);
      \draw [rounded corners=0.1*\hc cm] (-0.475*\r,0.2*\hc) rectangle (0.475*\r,0.4*\hc);
      \draw (-0.45*\r,0.4*\hc) arc (-90:0:0.05*\r cm and 0.4*\hc cm) --%
            (0.4*\r,0.8*\hc) arc (180:270:0.05*\r cm and 0.4*\hc cm) -- cycle;
      \draw (-0.375*\r,0.8*\hc) rectangle (0.375*\r,\hc);
    \end{scope}
  }
  % SHAFT
  \draw (-0.35*\r,-0.5*\hs) rectangle (0.35*\r,0.5*\hs);
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yrad{0.35*\r*sin(10)}      % semiellipses y axis (always the same)
  \foreach \i in {-72,-36,...,72}
  {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xmin{0.35*\r*sin(\i-10)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xmax{0.35*\r*sin(\i+10)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xrad{0.5*(\xmax-\xmin)}  % semiellipses x axis
    \draw (\xmin,0.5*\hs-\yrad)  arc  (180:0:\xrad cm and \yrad cm) --%
          (\xmax,-0.5*\hs+\yrad) arc (0:-180:\xrad cm and \yrad cm) -- cycle;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is my column:

[image]

Comment: Excellent...and I am without words. :-)...Compliments.